# (VueJs) I can't use methods in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm trying to make a website where I have a home and a "Brazil" component. I'm using vue router to switch between home and Brazil. In Brazil there is a calculator but I cant use the methods used in the script tag. The calculator should ask for a grade input and then calculate the Average of it when the user clickes on Average. The calculation is correct. The buttons don't work. Does annyone know what the problem is?
Here is the code:

```
<template>

  <div>
    Brazil
    <h2>Grade-Calculator </h2>
    <div id="calculator">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(g,idx) in grades" :key="idx">{{idx+1}}. Grade : {{g}}</li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <label>New Grade: </label>
        <input type="text" v-model="newGrade" />
        <button v-on:click="addGrade()">Ok</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
        <button v-on:click="calcAvg()">Average</button>
        <p>Average: {{ sum }}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
  name: "Brazil",
  props: {}
};
new Vue({
    el: '#calculator',
    data: {
      grades: [],
      newGrade: 0,
      avg: 0
      //TEST
    },
    methods: {
      addGrade: function () {
        this.grades.push(this.newGrade)
        this.newGrade = 0
      },
      calcAvg: function () {
        let sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.grades.length; i++) {
          let zahl = parseInt(this.grades[i]);
          sum = sum + zahl;
        }
        //calculate average and print it
        console.log(sum)
        console.log(this.grades.length)
        return sum / this.grades.length;
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: did you try it with `addGrade` without ()

Comment: what error is it giving?

Comment: The `new Vue` part shouldn't be inside the `.vue` file. Most of the config options that you're passing to the `Vue` constructor should be inside your component definition instead. I suggest using Vue CLI to build a skeleton project so you can see how things are supposed to be laid out.

Comment: You're trying to show `{{ sum }}`, but you're not declaring it anywhere. On `calcAvg` method, if you add `this.sum = sum`, you'll see some difference. I think it'd be good for you to read this [article](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties).

Comment: @Ifaruki yes doesn't work either.

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran It's not giving any error. :(

Comment: @JEA check my answer, I just posted one, and if it doesn't work, feel free to comment

Comment: you only need to add `sum: 0` inside your data object, and change your `return` keyword inside the function to `this.sum` you understand?

Comment: That's the problem, you're declaring `let sum` and your template doesn't have access to it. I posted an answer, can you try it?

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran I forgot to write that the I first have to Add a grade and then I can calculate the average. So there is a Problem with addGrade maybe?

Comment: @lucas  I forgot to write that the I first have to Add a grade and then I can calculate the average. So there is a Problem with addGrade maybe?

Comment: @JEA I don't think so, but try to confirm by `console.log(this.grades)` in the line before your for-loop. If it doesn't, have you added `sum: 0` to the data object as I said earlier?

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran Yes I added "sum: 0" and it doesn't work with console.log

Comment: may I ask, are you using Vue CDN or VueCLI?

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran I don't know. I did a vue create "name" in powershell and it created the project.

Comment: great, that means you're using vue CLI, I'm gonna update my answer soon. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use two different patterns at the same time, on the same component! One is SFC (single file component) and the other is rendering a new Vue instance which replaces a particular element in your existing DOM.

From what you posted, it's unclear how you're using this in home. However, you seem to be exporting a very basic object (with a name and empty `props`) ***then*** you are creating a new instance of Vue inside your already exported SFC.

Vue is very flexible and you might get it to work, but it's likely a complication you don't really want.

I made a few minor other fixes:

- i replaced the average function
- i removed the `sum` method you reference but haven't created
- fixed type casting (don't use `parseInt` in JavaScript. Use `Number()`!).
- a few more details I can't remember

---

Here's how your component would get used with `Vue.component()` declaration:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.component('Calculator', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Grade-Calculator</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(g,key) in grades" :key="key">{{key+1}}. Grade : {{g}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <label>New Grade:</label>
          <input type="text" v-model="newGrade">
          <button @click="addGrade()">Add</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
          <p>Average: {{ average }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  name: 'Calculator',
  data: () => ({
    grades: [],
    newGrade: 0,
    avg: 0
    //TEST
  }),
  computed: {
    average() {
      return this.grades.length ? `${this.calcAvg(this.grades)}` : "n/a";
    }
  },
  methods: {
    calcAvg(grades) {
      return grades.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0) / grades.length;
    },
    addGrade() {
      this.grades.push(this.newGrade);
      this.newGrade = 0;
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Calculator />
</div>
```

And here's how you'd use SFC: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-ellis-0m0p2

---

There are more ways to create components in Vue:

- `new Vue({ el: '#elId' })` // replaces the element, using its contents as template
- `Vue.extend({})` // typically used in typescript apps, for typings inheritance
- declaring them as classes with `@Component` decorator, if using the [`vue-class-component`](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) plugin (it's just a wrapper around `Vue.extend()`, at core).

There might be more, but the ones mentioned above are the most common.

Comment: Thank it really worked even with vue router. Don't know why but it works. Thanks XD.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using vueCLI, you don't need to declare your app element again, as it would have been declared for you in the "App.vue" component inside "src" directory. Change your script to this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Brazil",
        props: {},

        data: {
           return {
              grades: [],
              newGrade: 0,
              avg: 0,
              sum: 0,
              //TEST
           }
        },
        methods: {
          addGrade: function () {
            this.grades.push(this.newGrade)
            this.newGrade = 0
          },
          calcAvg: function () {
            let sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.grades.length; i++) {
              let zahl = parseInt(this.grades[i]);
              sum = sum + zahl;
            }
            //calculate average and print it
            console.log(sum)
            console.log(this.grades.length)
            this.sum = sum / this.grades.length;
          }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some small adjustments would do the trick.

```js
data: {
  grades: [],
  newGrade: 0,
  avg: 0,
  sum: 0, // Add this
},
```

Change this:

```js
return sum / this.grades.length;
```

to this:

```js
this.sum = sum / this.grades.length;
```

Comment: @JEA Do you want to automatically calculate the average after adding a new grade?

Comment: @yes I want to calculate the average after adding a new grade immediately

Comment: @JEA add `this.calcAvg()` after `this.newGrade = 0` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the `data` and `methods` sections in the `export default` section like follows.

```
export default {
  name:"Brazil",
  props:[], // add properties here
  data:()=>{
      return {
         // create your data variables here
      }
  },
  methods:{
     // create your methods here
  }
}
```

In the Vue.js component structure, the `html` template part is associated with the `export default` next to it. And when you're using a method inside the template, it will check the method in the `methods` section of `export default` part.